# HTML5 Drag and drop - trying to drag element and not removing it from the source div

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am to drag and drop elements to the target div and also without removing it from the source div

Using below code drag and drop works fine but I was trying to retain the element in the source div without deleting it

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<p>Drag the elements image into the rectangle:</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <div id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">Input</div>
  <div id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">Radio</div>
  <div id="drag3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">Checkbox</div>
  <div id="drag4" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">Dropdown</div>
  </div>  
  <br>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

CSS:

```
#div1, #div2 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

#drag1,#drag2,#drag3,#drag4{
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:5px;
}
```

Comment: You may want to use jQuery UI for this task and with custom element clone so that original one will not be destroyed. Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Aneeshmohan/qbxfbmtt/ and this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269901/jquery-drag-drop-without-destroying-dragged-item

Or you can append element to your div1 and div2 together.

Comment: thanks @Carrot--Show, problem is I cant use jquery and trying to accomplish with javascript

Answer (score 0):

Quite old question, just in case it helps someone:

You can actually close the html in the dataTransfer.
Eg:

```
 function dropClone(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
    }
```

Use the cloneNode to clone the source.